# c++ COM interface inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface, com

I was wondering what was the best way to achieve code reuse by inheritance in a COM application.

#### The Problem

It came to my understanding that the virtual inheritance model of C++ cannot by used in a COM environment because it is not language independent.

In pure C++ a class hierarchy could look something like the following:

```
interface IBase {
    virtual void BaseMethod() = 0;
};

interface IDerived : virtual IBase {
    virtual void DerivedMethod() = 0;
};

class CBase : public virtual IBase {
public:
    virtual void BaseMethod() override { /* Do something */ }
};

class CDerived : public IDerived, public CBase {
public:
    virtual void DerivedMethod() override { /* Do something */ }
};
```

This results in the following hierarchy:

[image: class hierarchy with virtual inheritance]

`IDerived` and `CBase` both inherit virtually from `IBase`.

Since virtual inheritance is not available in COM, the class hierarchy would rather look something like this:

```
interface IBase {
    virtual void BaseMethod() = 0;
};

interface IDerived : IBase {
    virtual void DerivedMethod() = 0;
};

class CBase : public IBase {
public:
    virtual void BaseMethod() override { /* Do something */ }
};

class CDerived : public IDerived, public CBase {
public:
    virtual void DerivedMethod() override { /* Do something */ }
};
```

This results in the following hierarchy:

[image: class hierarchy without virtual inheritance]

At first glance, there seems to be a problem with the ambiguity of `IBase`. This can be easily resolved by implementing the `IUnknown::QueryInterface` method.

The real problem is, how can `CDerived` inherit the implemented methods of `IBase` from `CBase`, namely `CBase::BaseMethod`?

In the case of virtual inheritance, `CBase::BaseMethod` can be inherited by dominance, but without virtual inheritance this cannot happen: In `CDerived`, the method `CBase::IBase::BaseMethod` is defined, however the method `IDerived::IBase::BaseMethod` is not, resulting in the class `CBase` still being abstract and not thus not eligible for instantiation.

One way, to resolve this would be to override the method `BaseMethod` in `CDerived` once again:

```
class CDerived : public IDerived, public CBase {
public:
    virtual void BaseMethod() override { CBase::BaseMethod(); }
    virtual void DerivedMethod() override { /* Do something */ }
};
```

Does this have any performance implications? Is there a better way of achieving what I want? Doesn't the repeated override of the function in `CDerived` defeat the whole idea of inheritance?

Comment: This question is based on a very broken assumption.  COM achieves language independence by the client code only ever seeing interfaces.  The implementation is *completely* invisible.  That allows you to do anything you want to implement the interfaces, and in fact using non-virtual multiple inheritance is the boilerplate approach.  Having only one function to implement QueryInterface, AddRef, Release for all the implemented interfaces is *exactly* what you want.  Any basic tutorial for COM shows you how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ATL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ax346b7.aspx) widely uses a technique that goes like this:

```
template <typename Itf>
class IBaseImpl : public Itf {
public:
  void BaseMethod() override;
};

class CBase : public IBaseImpl<IBase> {};

class CDerived : public IBaseImpl<IDerived> {
public:
  void DerivedMethod() override;
};
```

Now you have straight-line inheritance: `IBase` <- `IDerived` <- `IBaseImpl<IDerived>` <- `CDerived`.